# Misconception about proof by cases

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, inequality

> Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, s.t. $y>0$. Then $|x|<y \iff -y < x < y$.

I'm confused about how to join the cases in this proof into a single interval.

By definition, $|x|= x$ if $x \geq0$ and $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$.
So the proof lends itself to two cases.

Case 1: $x \geq 0$

Then $|x|<y \implies x<y$

Case 2: $x < 0$

Then $|x|<y \implies -x<y \implies x>-y$

But the cases are joined by an "or" statement, as opposed to an "and" statement, correct?

So it would be wrong to conclude that the solution lies in the intersection. That is, I cannot immediately conclude $-y<x<y$.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: In case $x \ge 0$ you need to prove not only $x<y$ (which you have done), but also $-y < x$.  Similarly, you need to prove two conclusions in the other case.

Comment: I see now... of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|x|<y\implies x\le \max (x,-x)=|x|<y\implies x<y.$$ $$|x|<y\implies -x\le \max (x,-x)=|x|<y\implies -x<y\implies x>-y.$$